# Show that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a vector space $V$ such that $S_1\subseteq S_2$, then span($S_1$ $\subseteq$ span($S_2$).

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x=a_1u_1+...a_nu_n$ for some $a_i$ in R and $u_i$ in $S_1$.
Then $x$ is contained in span($S_1$).
Since $S_1$ is contained in $S_2$, $u_i$ also contained in $S_2$.
And so, $x=a_1u_1+...a_nu_n$ is contained in $S_2$.
Hence, if $x$ is contained in $S_1$, then $x$ is also contained in $S_2$.

I wonder that my proof is correct.
Is there any contradictions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps you should swap the order of the first two sentences. Like so: "Let $x \in \mathrm{span}(S_1)$. Then $x=\cdots$, with $u_i \in S_1$". Also your conclusion doesn't seem to be the right one, since you conclude that $S_1\subseteq S_2$; but that was the hypothesis. You should conclude that... (complete the sentence)